# What's the proper way to extract data from database to present in a certain graph

Tags: c#, sql-server, livecharts

I want to ask the proper way to extract data from database that will be shown to a certain graph like ([LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/Wpf/Line)) I know graph has a common way to show data by adding a series of data for Y-axes like 4, 6, 10, 11, 2 and Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May for x-axes.

Now my issue is if the UI is asking dateFrom and dateTo for sales report say for example, 01/15/2022 and 05/27/2022 it would be January to May of 2022. So in order to present the data:

1. Do I have to extract data from Jan 15 to Jan 31, 2022 sum it up for Jan 2022?
2. For February 2022, I have to extract data from Feb 1, 2022 to the last day of Feb?
3. Same as number 2 for March and April?
4. For May, it would be May 1 to May 27, 2022?

So in SQL I will be creating an autogenerated SQL based on the above requirements?

So it would be something like this?

```
   SELECT
        (SELECT sum(gross_sales) from Sales A where A.id=Z.id where A.TrxDate >= '2022-01-15' and A.TrxDate >= '2022-01-31') as January,
        (SELECT sum(gross_sales) from Sales B where B.id=Z.id where B.TrxDate >= '2022-02-01' and B.TrxDate >= '2022-02-28') as February
   From Sales Z
```

My issue is if it is the proper way to do it? It'll gonna be tedious though so I want to make sure I'm in the right way. By the way, the SQL above might not be working but I'm just thinking of SQL in that way. The SQL will be autogenerated by StringBuilder of C#.

Comment: Most reporting layers have the ability to aggregate on their own, so providing simply the date and the `gross_sales` values should be more than enough; the reporting layer would aggregate those values into days, if that is your grouping for your chart. The requirements of the reporting layer depends on the reporting layer though.

Comment: Okay I got you but I think the Live Charts (lvcharts.net) is not designed to do that. So I have to manually add the aggregate values. Thanks for opening up my mind. I think Excel Graphs do what you said.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I created a algorithm. To do it

1. I have to calculate the number of months of from and to.
2. It checks the initial date for the first item in the List.
3. Initial date will be the from date, the next will always starts at 1st day of the month if the months count is more than one.
4. White it executes, it will checks the month of the current being executed whether it's January, February, March, etc.
5. It executes until it reaches the To date.